# SSH Show motd without re-connect

Tags: ssh, motd

As the title say I'm setting up the motd scripts for my server,
in the directory:

```
/etc/update-motd.d/
```

I want to see them without re-connect to ssh,
there is a command to display the ssh motd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files in `/etc/update-motd.d/` should be executable, and named in order, so I believe something like this should do it:

```
$ for i in /etc/update-motd.d/*; do $i; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your OS and version, some (older) Linux OSes merely "cat" the files, as opposed to executing them.  As guzzijason mentioned, your targets should be "executable" in order to be run, therefore, you should be able to call the the scripts directly from the command line, or restart your profile:

```
    source .profile
```

Again, this is all dependent upon your flavor of OS and version.

A good write up of this for Debian and Ubuntu types can be found here:  [Customize your MOTD...](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/)

Your mileage may vary.